# How do sites like Instagress bypass Instagram's API?

Tags: api, authentication, instagram, account

I just discovered Instagress.com, and noticed that they ask you for your Instagram username and password to automate certain activity such as likes, comments, follows, etc. on your IG account. However they do this without using IG's official API since their service is obviously against IG's TOS.

So I'm wondering, how are they technically able to do this? I was thinking they use something like Selenium, but this only automates web browsers and (for all I know) it's impossible to perform those interaction through Instagram's web interface.

Any ideas?

Comment: i know some use imacro scripts on web browsers to automate likes form web interfaces.

Comment: what makes you think they are bypassing it? perhaps they are just not triggering any major flags.. Although i wonder how long that will last.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked..and actually you CAN Like, Comment, and Follow via Instagram's web interface. So most likely they do use a browser and/or mask it as a mobile device. Also they are not using any IG app to authenticate your profile to any api app. Otherwise it would show up here: https://instagram.com/accounts/manage_access/

Answer (score 0):

the instagram web access can allow you like, comment and follow and unfollow